# what do these trace events stand for?

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, ftrace

I just learned to use ftrace and perf and there are some stuff they are in common I don't understand--trace events. I guess they are some kernel internal functions, ftrace will record their name when they're called if they're enabled. Is that right? All the evens are sorted in groups listed below. Would someone tell me what they stand for or where I can get information about them in detail. thx.

### block btrfs compaction drm ext3 ext4 fs ftrace gpio header_event header_page irq jbd jbd2 kmem mce module napi net power raw_syscalls rcu regmap regulator rpm sched scsi signal skb sock syscalls timer udp vfs vmscan vsyscall workqueue writeback xen xfs

Answer (score 0):

Each of those is the name of the code in the linux kernel which printed the log message. For example, rcu is the lockless list code.  It stands for Read Copy Update.  The names will roughly match up with names of files or directories in the kernel source.  Look in the [Documentation](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.11/Documentation/) directory of the kernel source for more information.